# If you have a string of characters, is it possible to substract each one? Java

Tags: java

```
for (int i= length-1;i>=0; i--){//reverses order of string.
        password_2 = password_2 + password.charAt(i);//store in new string
        System.out.print(password.charAt(i));
```

basically after I inverse the order, I need to subtract 7 from each character. So lets say i input: "kflre". I need to subtract 7 from the k, from the l etc..and I wanted to do it within my for loop. Is it possible or do I have to convert everything into ints before?

Comment: in your loop , cast it to integer ( not nessecary but for readablility ) , subtract and then cast it back to char

Comment: you want to encrypt it using cesar algorithm ?

Comment: This is not a "String of characters" (such a thing does not exist). The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) defines, that a `char` can be automatically converted to `int`, and you can then cast an `int` back to a `char`, although be careful since you deal with unicode-values and may get an unexpected/unprintable character.

Comment: Please do not ever try to implement a password hash algorithm yourself.

Comment: @AmerQarabsa Thank you so much, the only thing though is that I want to use the variable outside of the 4 loop. After I convert the password back to char, I need to print it outside of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to subtract 7 from the location of the letter i the alphabet and then produce that? for example h - 7 = a.

You could fill an `map<int, String>` with the alphabet and then use `.equals(theLetterEntered)` in a loop to get the location, then just do addition on the maps key to get the new letter?

a quick example:

```
    HashMap<Integer, String> alphabetMap = new HashMap();
    String strToCompare;

    alphabetMap.put(1, "a");
    alphabetMap.put(2, "b");
    //etc.

    for (int i=0; 1<26;i++){
        if (alphabetMap.get(i).equals(strToCompare)){
            //code
    }
```

Comment: `(char) ('G' - 7)` would be `'@'`, not `'a'`, and `(char) ('G' - 6)` would be `'A'`. Classes in Java start by convention with an uppercase letter (`map` -> `Map`).

Comment: @Turing85 You are correct, looks like math is hard on Friday, my answer reflects just the alphabet as an example.